# CASE expression "missing keyword"

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently trying to run the below SQL statement and am getting stuck on the `case` expression. I was trying to go off of other questions on here but am having no luck. Error being given when running the below is "missing keyword"

```
SELECT
   A.EQNO, A.ITEMNO, A.AVG_CYCLE, A.MFG_TYPE, A.ACTCAV, A.STDCAV, 
   A.ORIG_WO_QTY, A.TOTAL_FLOOR_DISPO, A.ORIG_WO_QTY - A.TOTAL_FLOOR_DISPO,
```

This is where I'm not sure

```
   CASE A.ACTCAV 
     WHEN A.ACTCAV = 2 THEN 
       (3600 / A.AVG_CYCLE)*2 
   ELSE 
     WHEN A.ACTCAV = 1 THEN 
       (3600 / A.AVG_CYCLE) 
   ELSE 'UNKNOWN' 
   END A.ACTCAV
```

This part seems good

```
 FROM   V_RT_CYCLE_PART_COUNTS A 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN MFGCELL B ON A.MFGCELL = B.MFGCELL 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN EPLANT C ON B.EPLANT_ID = C.ID
WHERE  A.MFG_TYPE = 'AIP-BLWMLD'
ORDER BY A.MFG_TYPE
```

Lastly, is it possible to take the A.ORIG_WO_QTY - A.TOTAL_FLOOR_DISPO / CASE Function results?

Trying to take the SQL and formulas from a crystal report I have created and throw it into a BI Dashboard

Comment: What is the problem? Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am getting an error stating "missing keyword" when using the above statement.

Comment: I see, well two things. Next time include it on the question. Then try simplify the query to isolate what is causing the error

Comment: `WHERE  A.MFG_TYPE = 'AIP-BLWMLD'
ORDER BY A.MFG_TYPE` If every row have the same type, no need to sort by type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are combining elements of an `IF` with both simple and searched [case expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html) syntax. You also have a table alias prefix on your column alias, which isn't allowed.

You can either do:

```
   CASE A.ACTCAV
     WHEN 2 THEN 
       (3600 / A.AVG_CYCLE)*2 
     WHEN 1 THEN 
       (3600 / A.AVG_CYCLE) 
     ELSE 'UNKNOWN' 
   END AS ACTCAV
```

or

```
   CASE 
     WHEN A.ACTCAV = 2 THEN 
       (3600 / A.AVG_CYCLE)*2 
     WHEN A.ACTCAV = 1 THEN 
       (3600 / A.AVG_CYCLE) 
     ELSE 'UNKNOWN' 
   END AS ACTCAV
```

In both of them the stray `ELSE` in the middle has been removed (you don't need that between `WHEN` clauses, only right at the end for a default).

However, your two `THEN` clauses will return numbers, while `'UNKNOWN'` is a string, which is going to throw "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes" at runtime. You either need to make the default a number, or explicitly convert the numbers to strings.

> is it possible to take the A.ORIG_WO_QTY - A.TOTAL_FLOOR_DISPO / CASE Function results?

Not in the same level of query, unless you repeat the calculation. You would need to use an inline view or CTE, something like:

```
SELECT
   X.EQNO, X.ITEMNO, X.AVG_CYCLE, X.MFG_TYPE, X.ACTCAV, X.STDCAV, 
   X.ORIG_WO_QTY, X.TOTAL_FLOOR_DISPO, X.ORIG_WO_QTY - X.TOTAL_FLOOR_DISPO,
   X.NEW_ACTCAV, (X.ORIG_WO_QTY - X.TOTAL_FLOOR_DISPO) / X.NEW_ACTCAV
 FROM (
    SELECT
       A.EQNO, A.ITEMNO, A.AVG_CYCLE, A.MFG_TYPE, A.ACTCAV, A.STDCAV, 
       A.ORIG_WO_QTY, A.TOTAL_FLOOR_DISPO,
       CASE A.ACTCAV
         WHEN 2 THEN 
           (3600 / A.AVG_CYCLE)*2 
         WHEN 1 THEN 
           (3600 / A.AVG_CYCLE) 
         ELSE 'UNKNOWN' 
       END AS NEW_ACTCAV
     FROM   V_RT_CYCLE_PART_COUNTS A 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN MFGCELL B ON A.MFGCELL = B.MFGCELL 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN EPLANT C ON B.EPLANT_ID = C.ID
    WHERE  A.MFG_TYPE = 'AIP-BLWMLD'
  ) X
```

The inner query needs to get all the columns you want available in the outer query, plus any calculations you don't want to repeat. The outer query can then refer to any of those, including the alias you assign to any calculated values.

Comment: Aditionally. Your case cant return two different data type. Right now return a float and a string. Also should use `3600.0` to make sure you get a float result

Comment: Thank you guys! Works perfectly now.